# Is there a need for private link when using lambda destinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-vpc

In a project I'm currently working on I have two configurations where I need to pass information from one lambda to another and Lambda destinations looks like the ideal solution. In the first I have two lambda functions deployed inside the same subnet, I would like to have lambda A pass to lambda B on success and to sqs on failure. The second configuration is the same except that lambda B does not live inside a VPC. When I try to have A pass to B in the first configuration (where they both live in the VPC) lambda A does not time out as it would if you were trying to pass to an sqs without a private link configured but lambda b does not get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a Lambda from another is not a best practice. Try [AWS Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc)

Comment: I do use step functions extensively and would have  loved to have used it as the solution but the issue is that we wanted it to stream data and process it as a stream across multiple functions. We did consider using step functions in express mode but it doesn't guarantee single execution. Eventually MSK (kafka) gave us what we needed but I left the question up as it wasn't a "what is the best architecture question" (because your right it certainly isn't the best approach)  but more of a "is it technically possible"